# Trouble with JTables in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

So I'm working on a GUI for a movie rental system in Java, and here is a method for displaying what the user should see.

```
public void displayUser() //displays user screen/functionality
{
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    adminCheck = 1;

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("Members");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    menu2 = new JMenu("Releases");
    menuBar.add(menu2);


    retrieveMember = new JMenuItem("Retrieve Member");
    menu.add(retrieveMember);
    retrieveRelease = new JMenuItem("Retrieve Release");
    menu2.add(retrieveRelease);

    JScrollPane c  = new JScrollPane();
    JScrollPane b = new JScrollPane();

    JTextField field1 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field2 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field3 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field4 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field5 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField field6 = new JTextField("");
    field1.setEditable(false);
    field2.setEditable(false);
    field3.setEditable(false);
    field4.setEditable(false);
    field5.setEditable(false);
    field6.setEditable(false);

    JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
    infoPanel.add(field1);
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
    infoPanel.add(field2);
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel("Social Security #:"));
    infoPanel.add(field3);
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
    infoPanel.add(field4);
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel("Phone Number:"));
    infoPanel.add(field5);
    infoPanel.add(new JLabel("Address"));
    infoPanel.add(field6);
    add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    TableModel memberModel = new MemberTableModel();
    TableModel itemModel = new ItemTableModel();
    memberTable = new JTable(memberModel);
    releaseTable = new JTable(itemModel);

    c.add(memberTable);
    b.add(releaseTable);

    String[] searchMemberChoices = {"Search Members By:", "Last Name", "First Name","Phone Number", "Member ID"};
    String[] searchReleaseChoices = {"Search Releases By:", "Title" , "Category", "Type", "Release ID" };
    searchMember = new JComboBox(searchMemberChoices);
    searchRelease = new JComboBox(searchReleaseChoices);

    add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(searchMember, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(searchRelease, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    repaint();

    insertMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    deleteMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    editMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    retrieveMember.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    insertRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    deleteRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    editRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    retrieveRelease.addActionListener(new MenuActionListener());
    searchMember.addActionListener(new ComboBoxActionListener());
    searchRelease.addActionListener(new ComboBoxActionListener());

}
```

I am implementing my own TableModel class(not shown), extended from AbstractTableModel.
The problem is that the JTables(memberTable and itemTable) are not showing up. I initialize the Tables with TableModel, declare two JScrollPanes,add one table per pane, and add the panes to the frame. I don't understand why they aren't visible. Can anyone provide some assistance?

Note: The tables are declared globally, outside the scope of this one method.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [JScrollPane API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), you don't want to add components directly to JScrollPanes since that squashes their viewports, but rather you want to add components to the JScrollPane's viewport as the viewport's view.

Change:

```
c.add(memberTable);
b.add(releaseTable);
```

to

```
c.setViewportView(memberTable);
b.setViewportView(releaseTable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at these lines:

```
add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(b, BorderLayout.EAST);
add(searchMember, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(searchRelease, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

You're adding two components to WEST and EAST, which won't work. You can only have one component per BorderLayout section. Note that you can **nest layouts** by adding components to a JPanel, and then adding that JPanel to your BorderLayout.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of this if you know of one, but isn't a Panel a Component? If you're only allowed one Component per section, how can multiple Panels fit in one section?

Comment: @KyleWeise They can't. Multiple components can fit inside a single JPanel. That JPanel can then act as the single component that you add to a specific section of BorderLayout. Google "java nested layouts" for a ton of examples.